# Probability of Marbles Logic

Tags: probability

I just did a problem where bag A has 10 red and 15 white marbles while in bag B, there are 6 red and 8 white marbles.  I figured out that obviously bag B would more likely have a red marble pulled out of the bag on the first try compared to bag A.  Now I have this scenario, A student stated the following: Bag B will more likely have a red marble pulled out of the bag first because both bags have less red than white, but there’s only 2 more in bag B and 5 more in bag A. Why is this student either correct or incorrect?

Now when I first viewed the statement I agreed with the students answer but not the reasoning.  However, I tried to get a counter example and couldn't find any.  For example I tried 6 red and 4 white for bag A and 15 red and 20 white for bag B and this reasoning gave the same result.  Can somebody give me a counter example that will work or explain why this reasoning is right.  I also feel a solution should be built on multiplicative reasoning but it appears the student doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Bag $A$:$\;\,3\;$reds,$\;8\;$whites.

Bag $B$:$\;\,1\;$red,$\;3\;$whites.

Then

- Both bags have less reds than whites.$\\[4pt]$

  Bag $A$ has $5$ more whites than reds.$\\[4pt]$

  Bag $B$ has $2$ more whites than reds.$\\[4pt]$

but a red is more likely to be had from bag $A$.

More generally, suppose

- Bag $A$ has$\;x\;$reds,$\;x+5$ whites.$\\[4pt]$

  Bag $B$ has$\;y\;$reds,$\;y+2$ whites.

In order for this to qualify as a counterexample, we want
$$
\frac{x}{2x+5} > \frac{y}{2y+2}
$$
which holds if and only if $2x > 5y$.

For my example, I chose $x=3,\;y=1$.

Comment: Why do you keep deleting and reposting the (almost) same answer?

Comment: To more closely match the stated scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In order to find a counterexample for this question, you need the following two statements to be true:

- One is more likely to pull a red marble from Bag A than Bag B.
- In Bag B, there are 2 more white marbles than red marbles. In Bag A, there is a smaller number more white marbles than red marbles.

Do you see how to make these two conditions happen at once?

Answer (score 0):

For your counter-argument, make a more extreme example.

Bag C has 1 red marbles and 2 white marbles in the bag.

It has the lowest probability of drawing a red marble, but there is only one more white marble.

In all cases what we should be looking at is the ratio of red to white marbles and not the numbers of either.